# Spring GraphQl : access the parent argument in @SchemaMapping

Tags: graphql, spring-graphql

I have below graphQL with `year` as an input to the query.

```
type Query {
    getResult(year:Int):Parent
}

type Parent {
    child: Int
}
```

Can refer to the same argument in child?

I tried with `@Argument`, it worked for `getResult` method, but gave null for `year` argument in `child` method

```java
    @QueryMapping(name="getResult")
    public Parent getResult(@Argument Integer year) {}

    @SchemaMapping(typeName = "Parent", field = "child")
    public Integer child(Parent parent, @Argument Integer year) {}
```

I tried adding input to child separately like this `child(year:Int): Int` and it worked, but then that is not the right way as we have 2 inputs serving the same purpose.